# How can we achieve excel ceiling function with significance value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ceil

How can we apply excel ceiling function with significance value in SQL server ?

```
=Ceiling(10,3)
```

it should return 12, because 12 is roundup nearest to 3

```
=Ceiling(36,7)
```

it should return 42, because 42 is roundup nearest to 7

More examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDYI.png

Answer (score 2):

You can use arithmetic:

```
select ceiling(10 * 1.0 / 3) * 3
```

The `1.0` is to avoid integer division.  If the value is numeric or float, then it is not needed.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e5af36a42d6be10e034edaff0fd0e879) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You could just do `ceiling(10 / 3.0) * 3`

Comment: @Charlieface . . . .The original values in the question don't have decimal points and iI didn't think it appropriate to change the values.

Comment: with this formula, we get 10 but our answer should be 12

Comment: @Asfan . . . This answer cannot return `10` because that is not a multiple of `3`.  I added a db<>fiddle to show that it works.